# Отличие abstarct и interface в Java Core

Tags: java

друзья!

Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, в чем отличие реализации классов в виде abstarct от interface?

По факту сейчас вижу, что и то, и то реализует модель с данными для последующей реализации новых классов.

Как я сейчас вижу, что в обоих случаях пишется сама сигнатура, без тела,а уже в наследниках идет реализация.

Не пойму разницу.

Спасибо!

Comment: как и всегда было: abstract - для расширения в наследниках, interface для имплементации конкретного поведения независимо от типа (можно крыль пределать самолёту, а можно птице, а можно рыбе)

Comment: Ну как минимум потому, что унаследовать вы можете только один класс, а расширять интерфейсами можно сколько угодно. К тому же, абстрактный метод может иметь поля, а его методы не всегда обязаны предоставлять "обязательный контракт"

Answer (score 0):

у класса есть состояние - поля типа int, boolean и т.д. и поведение - методы.

**абстрактный класс** - это такой недо класс, имеющий своё состояние и поведение, с условием, что мы не можем создать экземпляр этого класса и от него можем наследоваться, менять его свойства и поведение. (унаследовать можем только один класс)
**интерфейс** - это поведение, контракт. (расширять интерфейсами можем сколько угодно)
например есть у нас абстрактный класс студент

```
abstract class Student {
    abstract void toStudy();
}
```

и есть класс медик, который наследуется от класса студент со своей реализацией метода учиться

```
public class Medik extends Student {
    @Override
    void toStudy() {
        System.out.println("учусь из-за всех сил");
    }
```

и есть интерфейсы бухать и курить

```
interface Drinkable {
    default void toDrink() {
        System.out.println("бухаю");
    }
}

interface ISmoke {
    void smoke();
}
```

и создаём класс хороший медик со своей реализацией

```
class GoodMedik extends Student implements ISmoke,Drinkable{
    @Override
    public void smoke() {
        System.out.println("не курю");
    }

    @Override
    void toStudy() {
        System.out.println("учусь нормально");
    }

    @Override
    public void toDrink() {
        System.out.println("не бухаю");
    }
}
```

создаём класс плохой медик

```
class BadMedik extends Student implements ISmoke,Drinkable{
    @Override
    public void smoke() {
        System.out.println("курю");
    }

    @Override
    void toStudy() {
        System.out.println("учусь плохо");
    }

    @Override
    public void toDrink() {
        System.out.println("бухаю");
    }
}  

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BadMedik medik = new BadMedik();

        medik.smoke();//курю
        medik.toStudy();//учусь плохо
        medik.toDrink();//бухаю

    Student student = new BadMedik();

    student.toStudy();//учусь плохо
    }
}
```

а для лучшего понимания, скачай и почитай эту книжку [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

она на 300 страниц, про ооп там около 150стр.
**Объектно-ориентированное мышление  Мэтт Вайсфельд**

ещё пример с коллекциями

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// создаём через интерфейс связный список
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add("1111");
//через интерфейс меняем реализацию 
        list = new ArrayList<>(list);
        list.add("222");
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем дефолт в интерфейсе? Я тут подумал немного и решил, что надо порекомендовать разработчикам языка добавить abstract на interface, чтобы нельзя было такого делать.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Книгу обязательно прочту! Сейчас штудирую шилдта и дударя на ютуб.

Comment: @RomanC в целом было сделано это для лямбд. в ответах дубликатах гляньте